# FileSystemWatcher stops raising events after a period of time

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, garbage-collection, filesystemwatcher

We have built a window service that listens to folders with `FileSystemWatcher`, when created we process the file and so on. But after couple of days the event stops working.

- Is it possible that it being collected by the garbage collector (GC)?
- Does the GC collect it holding class (which is a singleton)?
- Should I use a weak event?
- Do I have a bug that means the event gets unregistered?

---

What i think the problem is, that FSW has an internal buffer, when it overflows its an error, take a look in this [article](http://blog.tcx.be/2007/01/filecreationwatcher.html) that offer code to solve this problem.
Hope this help anyone.

Comment: These are very vague questions, and are difficult to answer without more context. The garbage collector won't collect anything that still has a reference to it (in an object that itself isn't collectible, etc), so as long as you are keeping a reference to your singleton, you should be okay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A couple of things to try, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397744/net-windows-service-with-timer-stops-responding):

- In the timer tick event handler, stop your timer before doing your tick event handling, and restart it before exiting the handler
- Wrap your timer code in a try/catch block to see what's happening.
- Read [the Elapsed event of the System.Timers.Timer class is not raised in a Windows service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842793) bug description/fix and see if that helps you.

In summary:

```
protected virtual void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // stop your timer
    this.timer.Stop();

    try
    {
        // TODO: add event handler specifics
    }
    catch
    {
        // TODO: add some logging to help you see what's going on
    }        

    // restart your timer
    this.timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i have done in our `Timer` classes, yet in our `FileSystemWatcher` the events stop responding after some time

Comment: Looks like you are using the 3rd suggestion as the answer to your ealier post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166339/timers-under-window-service-stop-working-after-couple-of-days

Comment: How is this answer even related to the question? The question is about `FileSystemWatcher`, the answer is about `Timer`.